# How to get a response from this server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I found this apparently lovely example of building a SQL web app online:
https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-implement-a-frontend-for-reactjs-and-mysql-application
https://www.educative.io/answers/how-to-implement-a-server-for-reactjs-and-mysql-application

I downloaded the repository code into a structure like this:

```
KhalidExample
-------------------
     frontend: contents of front end repository
     server: contents of backend repository
```

I start the server code and it nicely says,
"server is running on 3002"

But then I try to visit http://localhost:3002/ and it replies

> Cannot GET /

If I improve the address to match some paths that I see in the code and write
http://localhost:3002//api/get
it replies

> Cannot GET //api/get

Obviously I'm missing something basic, can someone please tell me what?

Comment: There might need to be 2 servers running, one for the Frontend + one for the Backend (at different port numbers). The browser loads the Frontend through server #1, and the code inside the Frontend then sends API calls to server #2.

Comment: from glancing at the server-side code shown in the link, it seems that `http://localhost:3002/api/get` should return some data. You seem to be trying this with 2 `/`s before `api` for some reason.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, Robin. I see now that this version of the address is evoking another error within the server, so I can now go and address that.

Comment: And thank you, Peter for clarifying that. Now (total noob status painfully evident :)  I'm trying to understand how to deploy that front end. What exactly would I set up to make that happen?

Comment: Okay, I found the answer for the front end:  `npm start`, executed in the directory that contains package.json.  That little script is amazing: it starts up some kind of boilerplate server that serves up index.js on port 3000. AND THEN it also starts up a page on your browser pointed at localhost:3000 . Marvelous! Who knew that a "package manager" would do all that?